# Django 1.6: MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, view

I'm trying to implement an average time feature that will allow users to input waiting time for doctor. But I keep getting this error and I've no clue how to fix it. I've tried researching but I'm still confused.

```
Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "views.py" in addWaitingTime
  111.     time = escape(post['time'])
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py" in __getitem__
  301.             raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))

Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /waiting_time/
Exception Value: "'time'"
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def addWaitingTime(request):
    post = request.POST
    time = escape(post['time'])
    doctor_seeker = post['userId']
    doctor = post['doctorId']

    if len(time) > 1:
        newTime = WaitingTime(time=time, doctor_seeker_id = userId, doctor_id = doctorId)
        newTime.save()

    url = "/docprofile/"+str(doctor_id)+"/"
    return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

models.py

```
class WaitingTime(models.Model):
    time_choices = ( (10, 'Less than 10 Minutes'), (20, 'Less than 20 Minutes'), (30, 'Less than 30 Minutes'))
    time = models.IntegerField(choices = time_choices)
    doctor_id = models.IntegerField()
    doctor_seeker_id = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s" % (self.time, self.doctor_id)

class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic)
class DoctorSeeker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is no variable 'time' in the post object.

What I would suggest is:

1) Have a look at what the post object looks like, by printing it out or writing it to a file. (I think you might be using get instead of post.)

2) When you work with user inputted data always expect that it might be different to expected. (A malicious user or a spider may be crawling your site.) Rather use:

```
time = post.get('time')
if time:
    time = escape()
else:
    # No time value was submitted ....
```

Comment: I get global name 'post' is not defined if I use what you stated above.

Comment: I thought you would realize that it must happen after your `post = request.POST`

Answer (score 0):

As cchristelis says, the error is because you don't have a `time` value in your POST data.

Really for this sort of thing you should be using Django's [forms framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/). That is the proper tool for validating user input and doing something with it.